# "index.js: not found" error when trying to run project

Tags: javascript

When using the run command

```html
"scripts": {
    "start": "index.js"
},
```

on package.json, it returns a "index.js: not found" even when the index.js file is clearly there. Any help to solve this problem?

Comment: i hope you are running command  "npm run start" ? 
in that case try changing your script as
"start": "node ./index.js"

Comment: Scripts are run by passing the line as a script argument to `sh`.  [See docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#exiting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell how to run index.js, try adding `node` at start

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
},
```